# What are functions and classes/objects called that are native to the programming language?

Tags: function, class, native

What are those `functions` and `classes`/`objects` called that are pre-written for you from the get go when you program or that you can use from a `library`/`pod`?

For example, I would refer to `func myFunction(){}` simply as "My own code". And I refer to code like `func viewDidLoad(){}` or `func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint)` as "native code" in a lack of a better term. So my question is simply, is there a better, more technical term for this "native" code?

Comment: "Standard Library/Framework" or "Common Library/Framework" is probably the most common terms to be used across the industry. But "Native code" usually refers to code that is being compiled to run directly on the processor (C++, Swift, ObjC), and not in a virtual/scripting environment (like Java, Ruby, PHP, etc.)

Comment: Thank you @Claus, that was useful!

Comment: FYI - None of your examples are native to "the programming language". The `viewDidLoad` method is available in at least 3 or 4 programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might just say that it’s from a specific framework. For example `func viewDidLoad() {}` is from NSViewController or UIViewController, which are part of the frameworks AppKit and UIKit, respectively.